# Leaflet map from REST service adding custom markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am successfully pulling in a SharePoint 2013 list using the following:

```
function LeafletDemoList(){
$.ajax({ 
    url: "SITEURL/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Leaflet%20Demo%20List')/items", 
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){  
                  var mapMarker = "{icon:" + item.Marker_x0020_Type.replace(/ /g,'') + "}";
                  var latlng = item.Latitude_x002c_Longitude.split(",");
                  L.marker([latlng[0],latlng[1]],mapMarker).addTo(map).bindPopup(item.Title);
        });
    },
    error: function(error){
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
}
```

The custom map markers are not showing up. I can see that the field is being pulled in correctly... (ie Forest shows when alert(mapMarker) test is done). The leaflet blue markers show just fine, the individual custom markers show fine:

```
L.marker([latlng[0],latlng[1]],{icon:Forest}).addTo(map).bindPopup(item.Title);

var Forest = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'SITEURL/SiteAssets/map-assets/images/forest.png',
    iconSize:     [21, 23], 
    popupAnchor:  [0, -8] 
});
```

but when I try and pull them from my list using my variable only the blue markers show:

```
L.marker([latlng[0],latlng[1]],MapMarker).addTo(map).bindPopup(item.Title);
```

I have attempted to write it a few different ways:

```
L.marker([latlng[0],latlng[1]],{icon:item.Marker_x0020_Type.replace(/ /g,'')}).addTo(map).bindPopup(item.Title);

L.marker([latlng[0],latlng[1]],"{icon:"+item.Marker_x0020_Type.replace(/ /g,'')+"}").addTo(map).bindPopup(item.Title);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I get a Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

item.Marker_x0020_Type is equal to a stripped text only string containing only one of the following: **forest** or **region** or **other** I am using the .replace(/ /g,'') to be certain there are no extra spaces.

Comment: It would be helpful if you supply some data examples so we can see what type of data has been set for `Marker_x0020_Type`

Comment: @iH8 updated. There are only text options available and they match what the custom markers variable is. I have confirmed this through console.log()... The correct data is coming in, but not writing to the icon:mapMarker spot. Is icon: not looking for a text string? Do I need to cast it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a string to reference a variable you've set earlier you can use bracket notation:

```
var foo = 'my string';
var bar = 'foo';

// The following all output 'my string' to your console.
console.log(foo);
console.log(this['foo']);
console.log(this[bar]);
```

Using that in your code:

```
var icons = {
    'Forest': L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'SITEURL/SiteAssets/map-assets/images/forest.png',
        iconSize:     [21, 23], 
        popupAnchor:  [0, -8] 
    }),
    'Region': L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'SITEURL/SiteAssets/map-assets/images/region.png',
        iconSize:     [21, 23], 
        popupAnchor:  [0, -8] 
    }),
    'Other': L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'SITEURL/SiteAssets/map-assets/images/other.png',
        iconSize:     [21, 23],
        popupAnchor:  [0, -8] 
    })
}

var iconName = item.Marker_x0020_Type.replace(/ /g,''); // Forest
var markerOptions = {icon: icons[iconName]}; // the same as calling icons['Forest']
var latlng = item.Latitude_x002c_Longitude.split(",");
L.marker([latlng[0],latlng[1]], markerOptions).addTo(map).bindPopup(item.Title);
```

Comment: This worked. However, I am not 100% sure I understand. Since I was trying to show it as a string rather than an object it was having issues?

Comment: You want to reference a variable called `Forest` in your current scope by using `{icon: item.Marker_x0020_Type}`. Assuming item.Marker_x0020_Type holds the string 'Forest'. Doing it that way it would be interpreted as: `{icon: 'Forest'}` not as `{icon: Forest}`. You could have used `{icon: this[ item.Marker_x0020_Type]}` which would have worked because it's the same as calling: `{icon: this['Forest']}` or `{icon: Forest}`